# Check if letter exist in a string and replace all those letters with specific letters php

Tags: php

Let's say i have a string like this: "Sóc Trăng".

What i want to do is check whether ó and ă exist in the string "Sóc Trăng". If those two letters exist in the string, I want to replace ó with o and ă with a.

How can i do so in php?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php - some useful reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use [`str_replace`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwidhcnc3ITRAhWbO1AKHaBxCrUQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fphp.net%2Fmanual%2Fen%2Ffunction.str-replace.php&usg=AFQjCNGS6JUROp9_Vbnwh14k3g254nqPWw) for it

```
$str = "Sóc Trăng";
echo str_replace( array('ó', 'ă'), array('o', 'a'), $str);
```

[output](https://3v4l.org/K9P2u)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: exactly what i need. thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
$str = "Sóc Trăng";
str_replace("ó","o",$str);
str_replace("ă","a",$str);
```

Thats it.